# How can I integrate Magento in a site?

Tags: 7

Does anyone know of a way to integrate Drupal 7 with Magento?

I see that the Magento module doesn't have a version for Drupal 7, but I'd like to keep my Drupal installation shiny and new at the start of the project. I'm talking to the powers that be about using the commerce module instead, but I suspect that's going to be a non-starter.

Comment: May you be more clear? why do you want to use magento with drupal if drupal has got it's own e-commerce distribution? http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart

Comment: drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart includes the latest Drupal7 ,the latest ecommerce modules and the lates ctools, views and some other basic no-core modules. Install it as a new drupal installation and choose the commerce profile. here there is a tutorial http://drupal.org/node/1291116 you can find others online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and simplest way to integrate drupal with magento is using magento API. http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html. Magento API provides all the functions necessary for e-commerce operation. You can get the list of all categories, products, product reviews, shopping cart feature etc.